# fractional quotient of division of two function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am having two equation pairs from two different sensors, The equation represent the radial and tangential accelerations. The equations are shown in this link.

[SeeEquationsHere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkvBG.png)

As we have placed the sensor along its radius and hence, the theta , d(theta)/d(t)  and second derivative of theta will give the same result.

How can i find the ratio between ar1 and ar2 and also the ratio between at1 and at2?